# Postgres row level security insert returning

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

Given the following snippet from my schema:

```
create table users (
  id   serial primary key,
  name text not null
);

create table user_groups (
  id   serial primary key,
  name text not null
);

create table user_user_group (
  user_id       integer not null references users(id),
  user_group_id integer not null references user_groups(id)
);

grant all on users to staff;
grant all on user_groups to staff;
grant all on user_user_group to staff;

create function can_access_user_group(id integer) returns boolean as $$
  select exists(
    select 1
    from user_user_group
    where user_group_id = id
    and user_id = current_user_id()
  );
$$ language sql stable security invoker;

create function can_access_user(id integer) returns boolean as $$
  select exists(
    select 1
    from user_user_group
    where user_id = id
    and can_access_user_group(user_group_id)
  );
$$ language sql stable security invoker;

alter table users enable row level security;
create policy staff_users_policy
  on users
  to staff
  using (
    can_access_user(id)
  );
```

Please assume the `staff` role, and `current_user_id()` function are tested and working correctly. I'm hoping to allow the "staff" role to *create users in user groups they can access* via the `user_user_group` table.  The following statement fails the `staff_users_policy`:

```
begin;
set local role staff;

with new_user as (
  insert into users (
    name
  ) values (
    'Some name'
  )
  returning id
) 
insert into user_user_group (
  user_id,
  user_group_id
) 
select 
  new_user.id, 
  1 as user_group_id
from new_user;
          
commit;
```

I can add a `staff_insert_users_policy` like this:

```
create policy staff_insert_users_policy
  on users
  for insert
  to staff
  with check (
    true
  );
```

Which allows me to insert the user but fails on `returning id`, and I need the new user id in order to add the row to the `user_user_group` table.

I understand why it fails, but conceptually how can I avoid this problem? I could create a "definer" function, or a new role with it's own policy just for this but I'm hoping there's a more straightforward approach.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am also having it.

Comment: No, sorry.  I ended up using a definer function and manual checks.

Comment: Alright. I ended up doing the same thing.

Comment: @AtaiasReis  can you please provide an example?

Comment: @Akrambek I changed projects and I don't have an example anymore. However, you can take a look at PostGraphile's docs: https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/postgresql-schema-design/#authentication-and-authorization . Look for "definer", they explain it really well from what I recall.

Answer (score 1):

I just came around this problem too and solved it by generating the uuid before inserting it:

```
create or replace function insert_review_with_reviewer(
  v_review_input public.review,
  v_reviewer_input public.reviewer
)
  returns void
  language plpgsql
  security invoker
as
$$
declare
  v_review_id uuid := gen_random_uuid();
begin
  insert into public.review
  (id,
   organisation_id,
   review_channel_id,
   external_id,
   star_rating,
   comment)
  values (v_review_id,
          v_review_input.organisation_id,
          v_review_input.review_channel_id,
          v_review_input.external_id,
          v_review_input.star_rating,
          v_review_input.comment);

  insert into public.reviewer
    (organisation_id, profile_photo_url, display_name, is_anonymous, review_id)
    values (v_reviewer_input.organisation_id, v_reviewer_input.profile_photo_url, v_reviewer_input.display_name,
            v_reviewer_input.is_anonymous, v_review_id);
  end if;
end
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice way to avoid the problem, I'm annoyed I didn't think of it at the time!